# Playing a video with Xamarin for iOS broken after latest update

Tags: ios, xamarin, mpmovieplayercontroller, xamarin.forms

The following code in Xamarin for iOS was working fine prior to the Xamarin for iOS update to v2.0.50727

This is the code in a custom renderer in a Xamarin Forms app

```
 class WatchVideoRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    MPMoviePlayerController moviePlayer;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var url =  new NSUrl("http://192.168.12.4:8085/MediaUploads/1/211/520140731170618/DPM202.mp4");
        moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController();
        moviePlayer.ContentUrl = url;
        moviePlayer.View.Frame = new CGRect((float)((NativeView.Bounds.Width - 600) / 2), (float)((NativeView.Bounds.Height - 450) / 2), 600, 400);

        MPMoviePlayerController.Notifications.ObserveLoadStateDidChange(OnLoadStateChanged);
        MPMoviePlayerController.Notifications.ObservePlaybackDidFinish(OnPlaybackComplete);

        View.AddSubview(moviePlayer.View);

        moviePlayer.PrepareToPlay();
        moviePlayer.ShouldAutoplay = true;
        moviePlayer.Play();
    }

    private void OnLoadStateChanged(object sender, NSNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (moviePlayer.LoadState == MPMovieLoadState.Playable)
        {

        }
    }

    private void OnPlaybackComplete(object sender, MPMoviePlayerFinishedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

As i said this was working till day before yesterday, after which I installed 2 updates on Xamarin. iOS & this is now failing. All i see is a black canvas & the video never loads. 
No notifications from the MPMoviePlayerController are ever raised. 
There is a release of this app scheduled for next week & this last minute bug is causing me headaches. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Here is a sample code if someone would like to test in their own setup 
https://github.com/supreettare/moviePlayerDemo please change the URL of the video file in WatchVideoRenderer in iOS project.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes, this was solved using the latest bits from Xamarin. No changes in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar issue by pushing a new image context and that did the trick. I modified the code to include the BeginImageContext() and EndImageContext().

```
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new CGSize(1,1));
var url =  new NSUrl("http://192.168.12.4:8085/MediaUploads/1/211/520140731170618/DPM202.mp4");
moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController();
moviePlayer.ContentUrl = url;
moviePlayer.View.Frame = new CGRect((float)((NativeView.Bounds.Width - 600) / 2), (float)((NativeView.Bounds.Height - 450) / 2), 600, 400);
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to AVPlayerViewController instead of MPMoviePlayerController. Throw this code inside your OnElementChanged method.

My renderer was a view renderer and not a page renderer so you might have to tweak it a bit.

```
if(Control == null)
{
    AVPlayerViewController avpvc;
    AVPlayer avp;

    var url = NSUrl.FromString("SOME URL HERE"); //or NSUrl.FromFile 
    avp = new AVPlayer(url);
    avpvc = new AVPlayerViewController();
    avpvc.Player = avp;
    avpvc.ShowsPlaybackControls = true;

    avp.Play();

    this.SetNativeControl(avpvc.View);
}
```